# The script does not iterate over the lines of a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I need to make my script iterate through a list of servers, but I can't.
Suppose that `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.0.2` are listed in the file that will be read by the script, when executing it only the first line (`192.168.0.1`) is successfully processed and nothing happens with the second line (`192.168.0.2`).

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read in server names from afile
while read -r server; do
# Check if server is reachable
if ping -c 1 "$server" &> /dev/nul l; then 
    echo "Server $server is reachable."
    # Check if mount point exists
    if ssh "$server" "[ -d /path/to/mount/point ]"; then
        echo "Mount point exists on server $server."
    else
        echo "Mount point does not exist on server $server."
    fi
else
    echo "Server $server is not reachable."
fi
done < servers.txt
```

How to go through the entire list of servers successfully?

Comment: `ssh` will read the rest of the servers.txt file during the first iteration, preventing the `while read` part from seeing it. See ["Bash While loop read file by line exit on certain line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709042/bash-while-loop-read-file-by-line-exit-on-certain-line) and [BashFAQ #89: "I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

Comment: Yes, you can use FD 3 , but I still find `echo hoppa | ssh "$server" "[ -d /path/to/mount/point ]"` the easiest solution to explain.

Comment: Where should I need to make the changes

Comment: Thankyou all for your spontaneous replies. It worked

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments section, `ssh` command is consuming your script `stdin`.

Add `-n` option to `ssh` should prevent this (see [this](https://serverfault.com/a/607299)).

So change this line:

```
if ssh "$server" "[ -d /path/to/mount/point ]"; then
```

To:

```
if ssh -n "$server" "[ -d /path/to/mount/point ]"; then
```